# Should I dispose XtraGrid elements?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

Should I dispose XtraGrid elements if it was created in code (f.ex.: If I add EmptySpaceItem in LayoutView)? Or GC collects it?

Comment: Disposing/garbage collection in DevExpress grid is a nightmare. Their grid uses a lot of internal component references. The way I solved them is used DotNet Profiler tool on it. I suggest you can do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basiclly, No. The GC does that for you.

Because the GridControl is itself a control, it is stored in the forms `Controls` collection. It will be disposed then the form is disposed.

XtraGrid is itself responsible for disposing any objects that lives in the Grid.

If you were to add a custom event/property to the XtraGrid, when *you* are resonsible for cleanling up when disposed is called. But it is not the case in your senario.

Answer (score 0):

The Garbage Collector will do any neccesary work for you :-)
He search for unuseable Objects if your program dont work or if the memory becomes empty and delete them.